# Stretch Tableview to content size

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` inside a JavaFX `ScrollPane`, together with some other Views parallel to it. Something like this here:

```
<ScrollPane maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <GridPane maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" prefWidth="1100">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="Infinity" minWidth="0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="Infinity" minWidth="0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </rowConstraints>
        <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="2147483647">
            <PieChart fx:id="amountPerState" legendVisible="false" minHeight="300" minWidth="300" />
            <PieChart fx:id="amountPerComponent" legendVisible="false" minHeight="300" minWidth="300" />
        </VBox>
        <TableView fx:id="componentTable" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
            <columns>
                ...
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </GridPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

Now this double scrolling from the `ScrollPane` and the `TableView` is ackward. When I try to scroll inside the `TableView` the `ScrollPane` also scrolls. I would love to have the `TableView` go as high as necessary for it's content, so that there is only the scrolling of the `ScrollPane`. Any Idea how I can do that? Or other ideas?

Edit: For extra clarification, I assume the TableView should have prefered size so high that all it's content is shown without any scrolling necessary. Then there are probably no scroll bars, or I can just not show them with the policy. This is how I think you would achieve this, but I don't know how to figure out the tables content hight to make it it's preferred size.

I think it will be a bit worse in performance, since `TableView` has this row reusing, but I know that there are not to many rows in the `TableView`, so that there will be no performance problems.

Edit: Both the charts and the table are to big for the windows, so they all need to be in the `ScrollPane`

Comment: Just put the vbox in the scroll pane, and the scroll pane in the grid pane alongside the table...

Comment: @James_D so if I understand you right, you are suggesting that I have two scroll views next to each other. It would solve the problem. I however still feel like that a solution with a single scrollview would be nicer in this context.

Comment: The table comes with its own scrolling functionality. I guess I'm not sure what you want the UI to be.

Comment: @James_D I want it to be a table blown up to the size of it's content, so that no scrolling would be necessary